# How to use "pdftotext" on multiple pdf files?

Tags: php, html, pdftotext

Can someone here can help me on my problem ? I have this code on displaying output of pdf file on web using pdftotext

```
include ( 'PdfToText-master/PdfToText.phpclass' ) ;

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="pdf_file" multiple="multiple">
<input type="submit" name="SubmitButton"/>
</form>

if(isset($_POST['SubmitButton'])){
$pdf =  new PdfToText ($_FILES['pdf_file']['tmp_name']) ;
text =  $pdf -> Text; 
echo $text;
}
```

it works fine, But what im trying is to upload multiple files and display it on web all the files uploaded. I can't find any solution. Can you help me guys ? :(

PS: sorry my english is not that good. THank youuu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where you upload multiple file. you will get the files in array.
Therefore, you need to loop over the tmp files

```
function show_pdf_text($file){
  $pdf =  new PdfToText ($file) ;
  $text =  $pdf->Text; 
  echo $text;
}

if(isset($_POST['SubmitButton'])){
 if(is_array($_FILES['pdf_file']['tmp_name'])){
 foreach($_FILES['pdf_file']['tmp_name'] as $temp){
     show_pdf_text($temp);
  }
 }else show_pdf_text($_FILES['pdf_file']['tmp_name']);
}
```

Comment: it does say "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: can you vardump($_FILES); ?

Comment: sir i tried it again, the var_dump shows the files. What to do next ?

Comment: What's the results. Can you post the results here

Comment: array(5) { ["name"]=> string(71) "pdfexample.pdf" ["type"]=> string(15) "application/pdf" ["tmp_name"]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpB085.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(5224) }

Comment: This means you posting only one file not multiple

Comment: then what should i do ? :( can you help me ?

Comment: using foreach not working only giving error of "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: does it work on you ? i tried it and it only showing one pdf file not multiple

Comment: Can you change html input attribute name for pdf_file to pdf_file[]